# Whatsapp chats and media from internal storage

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage, chat

A few days ago, my Whatsapp deleted all my messages and media. Luckily those are still in my internal folder.

Is there any way to restore my Whatsapp chats and media from my internal storage as there is no backup for that?

Answer (score 0):

- In the internal storage, look for the databases folder with chat backup and rename the last backed-up file to msgstore.db.crypt12.
- For the media, make sure all of it is in the "Media" folder.
- If you re-install Whatsapp, they ask you if you want to restore data. you may try that as the last resort.